# where return goes on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm staring with Haskell and there's many things I can't get. I want to make a function that receive a int param and return a string, I want to use that param on the function but I could find how to do that.

this is what I got.

```
writePhrase :: Int -> String
writePhrase x = "test " ++ value ++ " hello"
    where value = x
```

if anyone got any reference of all posible options of how to create a function using Haskell, would be great. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `return` (which you probably should be staying away from for a couple more days, until you're comfortable with haskell syntax) - in your case it's just a type error since you try to append an `Int` to a `String` - which obviously doesn't work because an `Int` is not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`show`](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/stdclasses.html) which converts its argument to a string:

```
writePhrase :: Int -> String
writePhrase x = "test " ++ show x ++ " hello"
```

Comment: @BlaShadow That's a separate question, that's already been asked on Stackoverflow. I personally would recommend [lyahfgg](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) - Real World Haskell (especially the first couple of chapters) is decent too, but a bit outdated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `return` is a function that is only used in monadic functions, like ones that do `IO`.  Keep in mind that it is just a function, there's nothing special about it to Haskell, so it won't exit a monadic function early like you might expect coming from a C language.

But to address your problem, you simply have to convert the value `x` to a `String`, and you can do this easily with `show`:

```
writePhrase x = "test " ++ show x ++ " hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `Int` to a `String` via the `show` function:

```
writePhrase x = "test " ++ show x ++ " hello"
```